# Get all items in a dictionary where value meets a condition

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I have an unsorted dictionary where value of a key is an integer.

I want to get all keys where value is greater than some int `k`.

- approach 1: I can just easily loop over the dict and compare each value with int `k`. O(n)
- approach 2: I can sort but sorting a dictionary takes O(n log n) so approach 1 is better.
- approach 3: transform dict into something else? if so, to what? and is that worth it?

I am curious if this can be done better than O(n).

Comment: Do you only need to do this once, or repeatedly? If repeatedly, does the dict change between the searches?

Comment: `get all items` from an unspecified initial data set (unsorted) is always going to take at least `O(n)`

Comment: if you act at the creation of the dict, you can keep a sorted list of `(k,v)` sorted by `v`. In which case, finding the pivot will take `log(n)`, because of a simple binary search, but anyway returning the list of all pairs that match `v>k` will still be `O(n)`, because for all you know all n pairs are a match.

Comment: at least `O(n)` i think. you are talking about Python so you have to traverse all key-value pairs in the dictionary. i would recommend to use `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Python dicts are unsorted (they are hash tables), so when you're talking about sorting a dict, you're really talking about a different data structure.

If you only need to do this once, then `O(n)` is as good as it can be since you need to examine each of the `n` keys. Use a dictionary comprehension, and you're done.

If you need to do this repeatedly, there might be some mileage in moving to a different data structure. Whether or not it's worth it depends on how large the dict is, how often it changes, how many times you need to do the search, how many keys each search returns etc. To be more specific we'll need more information.

Last but not least, depending on the exact circumstances, moving from `O(n)` to, say, `O(log n)` is not always a win. For example, if `n` is small enough a linear search could well turn out to be the fastest. A good general strategy is to go with the simplest implementation and profile the code to see whether there's anything to be gained from optimizing it.